# Javascript: Efficiently move items in and out of a fixed-size array

Tags: javascript, arrays, caching

If I have an array that I want to be of fixed size *N* for the purpose of caching the most recent of *N* items, then once limit *N* is reached, I'll have to **get rid of the oldest** item while adding the newest item.

Note: I don't care if the newest item is at the beginning or end of the array, just as long as the items get removed in the order that they are added.

The obvious ways are either:

- `push()` and `shift()` (so that `cache[0]` contains the oldest item), or
- `unshift()` and `pop()` (so that `cache[0]` contains the newest item)

Basic idea:

```
var cache = [], limit = 10000;

function cacheItem( item ) {

    // In case we want to do anything with the oldest item
    // before it's gone forever.
    var oldest = [];

    cache.push( item );

    // Use WHILE and >= instead of just IF in case the cache
    // was altered by more than one item at some point.
    while ( cache.length >= limit ) {
        oldest.push( cache.shift() );
    }

    return oldest;
}
```

However, I've read about memory issues with `shift` and `unshift` since they alter the beginning of the array and move everything else around, but unfortunately, *one* of those methods has to be used to do it this way!

**Qs:**

1. Are there other ways to do this that would be better performance-wise?
2. If the two ways I already mentioned are the best, are there specific advantages/disadvantages I need to be aware of?

**Conclusion**

After doing some more research into data structures (I've never programmed in other languages, so if it's not native to Javascript, I likely haven't heard of it!) and doing a bunch of benchmarking in multiple browsers with both small and large arrays as well as small and large numbers of reads / writes, here's what I found:

- The 'circular buffer' method proposed by Bergi is hands-down THE best as far performance (for reasons explained in the answer and comments), and hence it has been accepted as the answer. However, it's not as intuitive, and makes it difficult to write your own 'extra' functions (since you always have to take `offset` into account). If you're going to use this method, I recommend an already-created one like [this circular buffer on GitHub](https://github.com/trevnorris/cbuffer).
- The 'pop/unpush' method is much more intuitive, and performs fairly well, accept at the most extreme numbers.
- The 'copyWithin' method is, sadly, terrible for performance (tested in multiple browsers), quickly creating unacceptable latency. It also has no IE support. It's such a simple method! I wish it worked better.
- The 'linked list' method, proposed in the comments by [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling), is actually a really good option. I initially disregarded it because it seemed like a lot of extra stuff I didn't need, but to my surprise....

What I actually needed was a [Least Recently Used (LRU) Map](https://github.com/rsms/js-lru) (which employs a doubly-linked list). Now, since I didn't specify my additional requirements in my original question, I'm still marking Bergi's answer as the best answer to that specific question. However, since I needed to know if a value already existed in my cache, and if so, mark it as the newest item in the cache, the additional logic I had to add to my circular buffer's `add()` method (primarily `indexOf()`) made it not much more efficient than the 'pop/unpush' method. HOWEVER, the performance of the LRUMap in these situations blew both of the other two out of the water!

So to summarize:

1. Linked List -- most options while still maintaining great performance
2. Circular Buffer -- best performance for just adding and getting
3. Pop / Unpush -- most intuitive and simplest
4. `copyWithin` -- terrible performance currently, no reason to use

Comment: How do you need to access the data structure? What about using a linked list instead?

Comment: Unless you're working with insanely massive arrays, memory really shouldn't be a concern. That said, performance is something you can measure...

Comment: I've never heard of a 'linked list'! I'll have to go look that up.  ;)  But in answer, the cache will only store unique items, and I'll need to be able to check for the existence of an item in the cache and retrieve it, or add the new item if not. I'd considered using an object rather than an array, and using `delete` to remove items, but as far as I know, there's no good way to keep track of the oldest and newest items in an object....

Comment: You are looking for a [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer)

Comment: **Assuming that you want to keep newest item as the first item and oldest as last** -  You need to `splice` the existing `item` and put it in the front using `unshift` (as the newest item). If the item doesn't already exist in your cache, then you can `unshift` and `pop`.

Comment: @FelixKling: I found [an implementation of a 'linked list'](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/data-structures-with-javascript-singly-linked-list-and-doubly-linked-list--cms-23392). It would definitely do the trick! But it also seems to have a lot of use cases (and therefore code) that I wouldn't even need. Do you really think it would be overall better to just using Arrays, if all I need is a circular buffer, as Bergi said?

Comment: @gurvinder372: I don't care if newest is at index 0 or array.length-1. They just need to be able to be removed in the order they were added.

Comment: @MarcusHughes Also share what size of cache are you looking for? What is the frequency of cache lookup you want to support? Is this supposed to be used on a browser or server? Just trying to understand why performance is a concern here.

Comment: @gurvinder372: Client-side. I haven't fully decided on cache size, but I'd like this code to be reusable regardless of the cache size of a given project. Would the answer to what's best for a small cache NOT be good for a large cache, and vice versa?

Comment: @MarcusHughes Usually when the scale/size changes, everything changes - unless you get lucky. But given that this is a client side operation, I don't see performance being an issue at all unless the algorithm is very very bad... I have given an answer, please check it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If I have an array that caches the most recent of N items, once limit N is reached, I'll have to get rid of the oldest while adding the newest.

You are not looking to copy stuff around within the array, which would take `O(n)` steps every time.

Instead, this is the perfect use case for a [ring buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). Just keep an offset to the "start" and "end" of the list, then access your buffer with that offset and modulo its length.

```
var cache = new Array(10000);
cache.offset = 0;

function cacheItem(item) {
    cache[cache.offset++] = item;
    cache.offset %= cache.length;
}
function cacheGet(i) { // backwards, 0 is most recent
    return cache[(cache.offset - 1 - i + cache.length) % cache.length];
}
```

Comment: Having read the Wikipedia article, you're right, pretty much what I'm after! That said, I'm getting confused by your code! I'm going to have to play with it a bit to see what's actually going on with the indexing arithmetic. How would this deal with deleting the oldest cache items, though? `cacheGet` just accesses, `cacheItem` adds.... How do I delete with a buffer, and also ensure I'm deleting the oldest item?

Comment: oK, I figured it out, Bergi.  ;)  +1 for this doing exactly what I need as well. It appears that I actually have quite a few good options! Now I just need to test them all.....

Comment: @MarcusHughes `cacheItem` just overwrites the old items once it encounters them.

Comment: The ordering of the array is bothering me:

Running for 95:

cache = new Array(5);
...
for(i=0; i<95; i++) { cacheItem(i); }
console.log(cache)

[
90 ,
91 ,
92 ,
93 ,
94
] 

Running for 94:
[
90 ,
91 ,
92 ,
93 ,
89
]

Comment: @the_real_one It's a ring, not a linear list.

Comment: @bergi but the stated problem is to pop off the last element and it’d have been the last inserted. In the cases I mention you get unexpected results for that.

Comment: @the_real_one They want to remove the oldest only when inserting a new one. Also notice that my simple implementation assumes a fixed size (initially filled with `undefined`), for a resizable ring buffer (below still fixed capacity of course) you need two offsets.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#copyWithin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/copyWithin).

> The **`copyWithin()`** method shallow copies part of an array to another location in the same array and returns it, without modifying its size.
>
> **Description**
>
> The `copyWithin` works like C and C++'s `memmove`, and is a high-performance method to shift the data of an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). This especially applies to the [`TypedArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/copyWithin) method of the same name. The sequence is copied and pasted as one operation; pasted sequence will have the copied values even when the copy and paste region overlap.
>
> The `copyWithin` function is intentionally *generic*, it does not require that its this value be an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) object.
>
> The `copyWithin` method is a mutable method. It does not alter the length of `this`, but will change its content and create new properties if necessary.

```js
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

array.copyWithin(0, 1);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Another method I hadn't heard of. Thank you! I'll check it out and let you know what I think.  :)

Comment: This seems to need additional code to move the `0` to the back. Also, what makes you think this is faster than what `shift()` does?

Comment: @Bergi, op need to add the newest item at the end, as i have understood the question.

Comment: (Unless you need to support __any__ version of Internet Explorer)

Comment: Looking at the output value (`[1,2,3,4,5,5]`), how is this a "rotate"? That last `5` should've been a `0`.

Comment: I can definitely see how this would work great! I like the fact that this is mentioned as a 'high-performance' method that doesn't change the array size or length in any way. And actually, I don't necessarily need 'newest item at the end'. Could go the other way, too! `array.copyWithin(1,0)` I need to edit my question's title, as there's the misconception that I'd want to move the oldest item around. Instead, I want to *delete* it. So maybe 'rotate' array isn't the best way to describe it, as that seems to be misleading people.

Comment: So.... would this method call + the assignment `array[i] = newItem` (where `i` is either 0 for the beginning or length-1 for the end) be a better approach than pushing and shifting (or unshifting and popping)?

Comment: i would try both methods an choose the one who has a greater performance.

Comment: I was curious to learn about `copyWithin` and tried to come up with a quick test to compare it to the other approaches: http://jsben.ch/i3BPC Not sure if I made any errors, but it seems to outperform `unshift + pop` by quite a lot as the cache size gets bigger. It looses to the *ring buffer* described by the other answer in every test I came up with, though...

Comment: the ring buffer does not really change the array, but the offset for the index. so yes that is *by design* the fastest way to move items in a pseudo way.

Comment: So much for 'a high performance method'! I ran tests on all three methods (ring buffer, unpush, and copyWithin) on Chrome 63, Firefox 57, and Opera 49 (Win 7 64 bit), and on all 3 browsers, `copyWithin` was overwhelmingly the slowest method. Even for cache sizes of 1k - 5k (and 10k items added), `unpush` was already 70x faster for the 5k cache (24ms versus 1712ms). For enormous cache sizes (100k), `copyWithin` even had a measurable millisecond delay for adding just ONE item (16ms). Add to that the fact that it isn't supported by IE 11, and this becomes a no-go. I was genuinely sad!

Comment: @user3297291: I don't know if this was true on all your tests, but at least on the link you provided, the ring buffer and copyWithin methods don't actually utilize the `SIZE` and `LOOP` global settings you specified. So if you adjusted those, only the unpush-based cache was getting affected. This may be what made it seem like copyWithin out-performed unpush? And in line with what Nina Scholz stated, the ring buffer did not scale at all with cache size and *only* with number of items added. But even that was minimal. Even crazy numbers like 10 million writes to a 1 mil cache took only 90-100ms.

Comment: @MarcusHughes ah I did include those later but I guess the share link didn’t automatically pick up the changes I made later. Sorry for that, hope the example still was of any help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `splice` the existing *item* and put it in the *front* using `unshift` (as the newest item). If the *item* doesn't already exist in your cache, then you can `unshift` and `pop`.

```
function cacheItem( item )  
{
    var index = cache.indexOf( item ); 
    index != -1 ?  cache.splice( index, 1 ) : cache.pop();
    cache.unshift( item );
}
```

*item* needs to be a `String` or `Number`, or otherwise you'll need to write your own implementation of `indexOf` using `findIndex` to locate and object (if *item* is an object).

Comment: This is actually a good idea. I hadn't thought of maintaining the order of *access* of each item. I.e. You could add items `[0,1,2,3,4]` then access items 1 and 2 while never accessing 3 or 4, but the order would stay the same. It makes a lot of sense for the order to change: `[0,3,4,1,2]`. I'll have to think on this one some more. But +1 regardless. :)

Comment: Although that doesn't necessarily make `splice` and `unshift` best. I'm curious how those measure up against the simple assignment operations utilized in Bergi's answer. More testing to be done.....